# How to save SURVEY PDF on the disk

Tags: reactjs, pdf, save, disk, survey

I want to save somes PDF created with 'survey-pdf' on my disk.
Actually, i can send the PDF but i can't save it on my disk.

My final code :

```
  return surveyPDF.save(filename);
```

Someone can help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
await surveyPDF.save(filename)
```

?

`.save` seems to be an asynchronous function that downloads the PDF file.

[From the docs](https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Pdf-Export?id=surveypdf#save)

```
    
Call save method of surveyPDF object to download file in browser. This is asynchronous method
```

#2 If the first method doesn't work, you can try this

```
function savePdfAsString() {
    const surveyPDF = new SurveyPDF.SurveyPDF(json);
    surveyPDF.data = survey.data;
    surveyPDF
        .raw("dataurlstring")
        .then(function (text) {
            //var file = new Blob([text], {type: "application/pdf"});
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            //a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            a.href = text;
            a.download = "surveyAsString.pdf";
            //document
            //    .body
            //    .appendChild(a);
            a.click();
        });
}
```

Here you are using the `.raw` function to transform the PDF into a `dataurlstring` and then downloading that. [Here's the docs for this](https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Pdf-Export?id=Save-Pdf#raw-dataurlstring)

*Not tested

Comment: Thank you but i dont wan't to download the pdf i just want to save it on my disk

Comment: Not sure I understand, does saving differ from downloading the PDF? Everything you save on disk (from the browser) has to be downloaded one way or another from the internet